# How to create a list containing an arithmetic progression?

Tags: python, list, append

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Example of what I'm trying to achieve]

What I'm tring to do is make the sum of a starting number X, and sum it by Y, and with each sum, add the numbers to a previously empty list:

```
lst = []

i = -0.5
tot = 0.025
while i <= 100:
    tot = tot + i
    i = i + 1

a = tot
print("value: ",tot)
print(a)
lst.append(a)
print(lst)
```

Though I'm unable to keep them as individual numbers, and they just get clumped together.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: `list` and `sum` already mean something in python. Don't redefine them.

Comment: Why is `lst.append(a)` not inside the loop? Don't you want to do this in every iteration of the loop instead of only once?

Comment: `print([-0.5 + i * 0.025 for i in range(10)])`

Comment: Ohh that makes sense, so if I add the append inside the loop, each value will get added to the list as they are equationed?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, everyone. Was a bit stuck on this, will read more about loops as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really about applying an incrementing multiplier to Y, so it is more suitably implemented by iterating over a `range` of multipliers.

To produce 4 items, for example:

```
i = -0.5
tot = 0.025
lst = [i + tot * m for m in range(4)]
```

Comment: Sorry, can't upvote your answer yet since I'm a new account. But it's helped a lot in understanding the directions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SauloManoel You can still accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: Just did that. Can't thank you guys enough